# Adding Global Mediation extension in WSO2 APIM 3.2.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

I have configured a global mediation extension as per the document. The file global_ext.xml is placed under wso2am-3.2.0\repository\deployment\server\synapse-configs\default\sequences.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="WSO2AM--Ext--In">
    <property name="token" expression="get-property('transport', 'Authorization')"/>
</sequence>
```

```
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) {
        String accessToken = (String) messageContext.getProperty("token");
```

However, the token property is not available in the MessageContext properties. Any idea what went wrong here? Or how to fetch the value of token in handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext)` method is some CustomHandler class which extends `AbstractHandler` ([Writing Custom handlers](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/extending-api-manager/extending-gateway/writing-custom-handlers/#writing-custom-handlers)), then it won't work as you expect.
It is because the **Handlers are running before sequence**. The message flow is described in WSO2 documentation: [Message flow in the API Manager Gateway](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/guides/message-flow-in-the-api-manager-gateway/#message-flow-in-the-api-manager-gateway) and looks like that:
[image]

So you can set some property in handler and read in sequence, the other way doesn't work.